# how to get the integer part of very large integer multiples of irrational numbers such as $\pi$?

Tags: computational-mathematics, big-numbers

Do I need exact value of $\pi $ upto say $100$ digits if my multiplier is order $10^{10}$.

Comment: Yes of course you need.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate Why do you say "of course"?  Is it **obvious** that you need $100$ digits as opposed to $10$, $20$, or $1000$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it depends.  Say you have a multiplier of $N \approx 10^{10}$ (it sounds like it's not exactly $10^{10}$ because that would be fairly easy).  You're asking whether $\lfloor N\pi \rfloor$ can be different from $\lfloor N\pi^*\rfloor$ when $|\pi-\pi^*|$ is as small as $10^{-100}$.  For simplicity let's assume $\pi^*$ is a truncated (not rounded) approximation to $\pi$ so that $\pi^*<\pi$.

Well, the contents of those two floors differ by only $10^{-100}N \approx 10^{-90}$.  That may seem like an insignificant difference, but it still matters when $N\pi$ is very close to an integer.  Most of the time you can compute $N\pi^*$ and you can see that it is at least $10^{-90}$ away from being an integer, and safely conclude that $N\pi$ has the same integer part.  But what if $N\pi^*$ is just, just below an integer and $N\pi$ is just, just above that same integer (resulting in different floors)?  What we'd really like to know is,

> How close can $N\pi$ be to an integer?  In other words, how small could $\|N\pi\| := \min \{|N\pi-M| : M \in \mathbb Z\}$ be relative to $N$?

This is the subject of an active body of research and is related to the notion of [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html).  It is known from continued fraction theory that for any irrational constant $\alpha$ there are values of $N$ where $\|N\alpha\|$ is smaller than $1/N$, but in the case of $\pi$ it occasionally gets much smaller (well-known example: $113\pi \approx 354.99997$).

In practice this is something we can control.  We already know enough digits of $\pi$ that we can compute (efficiently by using continued fractions) that for $N$ of order $10^{10}$ the above is essentially the worst case, and that $N\pi$ will never be less than $1/(300N)$ away from any integer.  That means you never need more than about 13 decimal places of $\pi$ to get the integer part for such smallish $N$, even if you are very unlucky and choose an $N$ where $N\pi$ is close than integer.

If we extend your question to much larger values of $N$ then this is where irrationality measure comes in.  We believe the irrationality measure for $\pi$ is $2$, as is known to be true for "most" irrational numbers.  A low irrationality measure for $\pi$ means that $\|N\pi\|$ doesn't ever get really, really small, so lower is better for our purposes.  But we only how to *prove* that it is at most $7.6063$, and that is a recent result of Salikhov (2008).

Salikhov's bound means that $\|N\pi\|$ cannot be smaller than about $N^{-6.61}$, at least for very large $N$.  Then for $N$ of order $10^m$ you shouldn't need more than about $7m$ digits of $\pi$ (as long as $m$ is large enough – I honestly don't know for sure how large it needs to be but in practice it hardly matters).

Of course, if you carefully choose the "wrong" irrational number $\alpha$ then you can easily rig it so that you may need a very large number of decimal places to correctly get the integer part of $N\alpha$: some numbers do have infinite irrationality measure (Liouville numbers).